# CSS styles are removed when served by ESP8266 running an ESPAsyncWebServer

Tags: html, webserver, esp8266

Tried to position text In an Image exactly like in the example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_text_center).
It works fine in [my space](https://campcontrol.w3spaces.com/centering_test.html) at w3schools. When I look at the css in the browser:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
}
```

But when the **exact same  html + css code** is running on the esp8266 nodeMCU, the positioning fails. Like Ben T stated, the width style is missing.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
}
```

So something goes wrong in the css-class "center".

This is the Code running on the esp8266.
The html file right now is in the same file.
The css-positioning also fails with the temperature string.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Hash.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include "LittleFS.h"

const char* ssid     = "ESP8266-Access-Point";
const char* password = "123456789";

// hard coded current temperature & humidity
float t = 15.1;
float h = 55.5;

AsyncWebServer server(80);

const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text</h2>

<p>Center text in image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="camper" alt="Cinque Terre" width="1000" height="300">
  <div class="center">Centered</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>)rawliteral";


// Replaces placeholder with DHT values
String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == "TEMPERATURE"){
    return String(t);
  }
  else if(var == "HUMIDITY"){
    return String(h);
  }
  return String();
}

//background-image: url(\"camper\")

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(IP);

  if(!LittleFS.begin()){
        Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
        return;
  }

  File camper = LittleFS.open("/camper.png", "r");

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
  });

  server.on("/camper", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(LittleFS, "/camper.png", "image/png");
  });

  server.on("/temperature", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", String(t).c_str());
  });
  server.on("/humidity", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", String(h).c_str());
  });

  server.begin();
}
 
void loop(){  
}
```

Has somebody experienced something like this before?
Thanks in advance for any kind of hints ;)

Comment: If you save the HTML and CSS as files on your computer and load them directly into the browser, do they have the same problem? If they do you can edit this question, delete all the C++ code and post just the HTML and CSS files as the problem will have nothing to do with the ESP8266 code and web server.

Comment: The `width` style is missing from the file that the browser downloaded. Are you sure you downloaded your latest version of the sketch to the ESP8266?

Comment: Updated the question, downloading the html+css file produces the same problem.
Somehow the width style gets chopped as Ben T stated

Comment: The style is missing as the template processing is removing the text between the `%` characters. I will also remove the DHT code from your question so it is a minimally reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template processor is used in:

```
request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
```

and from https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#template-processing

> Placeholders are delimited with % symbols. Like this: %TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER%.

So all of the `%` characters in the `index_html` string literal need to be escaped. e.g.:

```
top: 50%%;
width: 100%%;
```

Otherwise the ESPAsyncWebServer template processing will treat the characters between `%` characters as a placeholder.

i.e. the text `%;\n    width: 100%` is treated as a placeholder. Your `processor()` function only replaces the `TEMPERATURE` and `HUMIDITY` placeholders and any other placeholder is replaced by an empty string.

This means this CSS:

```
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
```

is replaced with:

```
top: 50;
```

This general problem is described in the issue https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/issues/644.